# find: treat slash specially

Tags: find

I'd like to use `find` to match a path but I found this:

> `-path pattern`
>
> File name matches shell pattern pattern. The metacharacters do not treat `/' or` .' specially; so, for example,
>
> ```
>   find . -path "./sr*sc"
> ```
>
> will print an entry for a directory called `./src/misc` (if one exists).

How can I make it only match files in the current dir? Do I need another tool for this job?

Edit. As suggested here's some details. To do this job there are `-maxdepth` and `-regex` for use. However, in real applications the path may be a variable instead of a simple constant here, where `-maxdepth` won't work well and `-regex` may look like an overkill. So I'd like to know if there is a simple solution with `find` to make it respect slash. Below is rsync doc describing its behavior which is very close to what I want.

Currently best solution is using regex, but if you know anything that can make it simpler that'd be welcome.

---

As an example of what I want, here is rsync pattern rule:

- a ’*’ matches any path component, but it stops at slashes.
- use ’**’ to match anything, including slashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-regex` instead. The pattern is anchored at start and end so you will need to use `.*` at the start and end probably. Use `[^/]*/` to replace a glob `*` that does not match `/`.  Eg:

```
-regex '.*/sr[^/]*sc.*'
```

---

There is a small Perl script [find2perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/find2perl.html) that claims to convert the arguments to a `find` command into an equivalent Perl script. Obviously, it will have the same pattern matching for `-path` as `find`, but you can edit it to accept another argument, say `-glob`, which would then use the system call `fnmatch()` to do the sort of globbing you want.  I did a quick modification to my version of `find2perl` as shown in this patch:

```
--- /usr/bin/find2perl  2016-02-04 19:28:48.000000000 +0100
+++ /tmp/find2perl      2018-07-31 20:38:10.034175198 +0200
@@ -58,2 +58,4 @@
     $out .= tab . '$File::Find::name =~ /' . fileglob_to_re(shift) . "/s$1";
+    } elsif (/^glob$/) {
+        $out .= tab . 'fnmatch("'.(shift).'", $name, FNM_PATHNAME|FNM_PERIOD)';
 } elsif ($_ eq 'perm') {
@@ -236,2 +238,3 @@
 use File::Find ();
+use File::FnMatch qw(:fnmatch);    # import everything
```

(The lines beginning `+` show the 3 lines I added). I needed to add packages `perl-App-find2perl` and `perl-File-FnMatch` for Fedora. You would need to find the equivalent on your system.

You can then run commands like

```
/tmp/find2perl . -glob './sr*sc' | perl
```

Comment: This is probably the only thing I can find right now. So using regex for such a simple task is not an overkill?

Comment: I added a Perl alternative that at least means you can use the glob syntax you want, instead of having to convert it to a regex. Perl usually runs very close to C speeds.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `find` from recursing into subdirectories, use `-maxdepth` flag

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "sr*sc"
```

Comment: True but if the path variable changes you have to take care of the depth variable. And if the path variable comes from elsewhere you don't really know the depth variable.

Comment: @Cyker What variable? You never mentioned a variable, you only said "the current directory".

Comment: @Kusalananda This is only a simple example pasted from man page. In more complicated situations the path may be a variable rather than a constant `./sr*rc`. The point is I'd like to know if `find` can treat slash specially so I don't want to make the example very complex.

Comment: @Cyker The question explicitly asks "How can I make it only match files in the current dir?" You need to update this and be clear about what you actually mean, preferably with examples.

Comment: @Kusalananda It's in the title but I added more details in question to make it even more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Some shells, such as `zsh`, `bash` and `ksh93` supports the `**` filename globbing pattern.  In `zsh` it is enabled by default while `bash` has to have it enabled with `shopt -s globstar` and `ksh93` with `set -o globstar`.

This means you should be able to do, for example,

```
for pathname in ./src/**/misc/*.c
    # process "$pathname" here
done
```

A few `find`-like tests, such as `-type f`, could easily be incorporated into this:

```
for pathname in ./src/**/misc/*.c
    [ -f "$pathname" ] || continue  # will not skip symbolic links to regular files though
    # process "$pathname" here
done
```